# is this a pre-plumbed shower drain? i think/hope it is but not sure

Tags: plumbing, basement

[image][image]

ok so i am trying to figure out if my basement is pre-plumbed for a shower. the close up is the small black circle in the bottom left of the bigger-view-picture. you can see it is preplumbed for a toilet.

Comment: That is more likely to be a sewer clean out than an a location intended for a fixture. I think the pipe is your water supply but it looks odd with a yellow handled valve.

Comment: @dan d. The pipe is most definitely his incoming water supply.  Right after the wall is the water meter.

Answer (score 1):

it is a clear out drain i found out

Comment: Hello. Thanks for supplying your own answer, but would you please flesh the answer out a bit (e.g. how did you find out?), and then mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Thanks!